# Generate array of limited combinations from another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, combinations

I need to generate `2D` array in rails from a set of given strings. For example:

```
days =[ "Monday",
     "Tuesday",
     "Wednesday",
  ]
```

Now I want to create a `2D` array and the data in this array will be fill by using `days` string in random manner.

Example:

```
[monday, tuesday, wednesday],
[tuesday, wednesday, monday]
...
```

and so on depends on given dimensions

How to do it?

**Edit**

I tried this

```
# global variable
@@test_array = %w(:sunday :monday :tuesday)

def get_data(row, col)
 @data_field =  @@test_array.permutation.to_a(col)
return @data_field.slice!(row)
```

If I pass `row:1` and `col:1` It is working but If i pass a big number like 20 in `rows` and `column` it is storing null in database.

**Edit-2**

```
days = ["monday, "tuesday"]
rows = 3
col = 3
```

It should return (one of the possible solution due to random generation)

```
[[monday, tuesday, monday],[tuesday, monday, tuesday], [monday, monday, tuesday]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) if you don't want repetetions in the subarrays.

- `col`<sup>**1**</sup>  ∈ [1; 3]
- `row`<sup>**2**</sup>  ∈ [0; 3]

```
days.permutation(col).to_a.slice(0, row)
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/u4T/3)

If you want repetitions in the subarrays, you can use [`Array#repeated_permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation).

- `col` ∈ [1; 3]
- `row` ∈ [0; 3<sup>3</sup>(= 27)]:

```
days.repeated_permutation(col).to_a.slice(0, row)
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/u4T/1)

If you want repetitions in the subarrays and also expand your column number to the custom, independent from length of the original array number, you can use [`Array#repeated_combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination).

- `col` ∈ [1; ∞<sup>**3**</sup> )
- `row` ∈ [0; `col`<sup>`col`</sup>]:

```
days.repeated_combination(col).to_a.slice(0, row)
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/u4T/2)

---

<sup>**1**</sup> *`col` is the number of elements in each subarray.*
<sup>**2**</sup> *`row` is the number of subarrays in the desired 2D array.*
<sup>**3**</sup> *The upper bound is specified as **∞** to represent that this value is not bounded by the length of the original array.*

Comment: Thanks! But where can i apply the limit of `rows` and `column`?

Comment: @AmitPal: Well, with specified argument from 1 to the _length_ you can control the number of columns, the number of rows can be cut off with [`slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-slice) method.

Comment: @AmitPal: Well, as I said, you can specify argument from 1 to length, in your case, from 1 to 3. It is all about possible combinations, you can't build 20 different combinations from 3 values – 3! = 3*2*1 = 6. So, you can have maximum 2d array of 3x6 and minimum of 1x1( or just empty array, if it counts).

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I wanted to generate a matrix from the set of given string with a given dimension. Please have a look at the `Edit-2` section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81758/discussion-between-amit-pal-and-suslov).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation but in http://repl.it/u4T/1 it always fill the matrix[0][0..col] with data[0]. Is there any way that I can shuffle it ?